# jQuery animate/scrollTop not working (chrome extension)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, jquery-animate

I am trying to implement a basic text message app and want the scrollable div to stay scrolled to the bottom, yet it always remains at the top. I have a div called message and inside that div I have another div called history. I am dynamically appending h1 tags to a div with the id of history using jQuery. After the for loop has run it's course, and all the content is appended to the history div, I have this line:

```
$('#message #history').animate({scrollTop:$('#history').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
```

However, no animations occur and the scroll bar stays at the top.

I have this css:

```
#message{
overflow: scroll; 
height:400px;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this usually means that you need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Without more information, it appears this question may be able to be duplicated outside of a Chrome extension environment. If so, you should consider using a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in your question so readers can immediately see what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `$(document).scrollTop(90);`

You can specify the height here which will scroll to your designated level.

Comment: I just tried that code, yet the div still stays fixed at the top.

Comment: can you add position:absolute; to your css? 

and then have you tried the height:'auto' attribute to the css?

Comment: When I add position: absolute, I can not see any of my messages anymore. I added height auto, which obviously extends my box past 400px, but still does not move the scroll bar.